# C++ Typecasting *(float*)&

Tags: c++

Kindly explain me the line containing variable `i` initialization does

```
struct vector
{
   float value;
};

int main()
{
    vector v3;
    v3.value = 5.0f;

    float i = *(float*)&(v3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A *bad* way to do `float i = v3.value;`

Comment: As a side note: It's certainly a bad idea to name something `struct vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
&(v3)
```

This takes the address of `v3` which is of type `vector*`.

```
(float*)&(v3)
```

Now we cast that address to be of type `float*`.

```
*(float*)&(v3)
```

Finally, we read the contents of that `float*` and initialize `i` with the value.

The validity of this rather convoluted process is covered here: [Does accessing the first field of a struct via a C cast violate strict aliasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747010/does-accessing-the-first-field-of-a-struct-via-a-c-cast-violate-strict-aliasing) In summary however, for the specific scenario described in the question, using a POD struct, the standard says that the cast is valid.

It would make much more sense to write

```
float i = v3.value;
```

Comment: Note this is legal due to 9.2 [Class.mem]/20: "A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member [...] and vice versa." This had to be possible in `C` to achieve an approximation of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

goes like this (i think:)):

1. you took v3, and asked for it's address (& operator)
2. then cast it into a (float*)
3. finally, you asked for it's content (* operator), and assigned it to i

looks about right?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?