# Best way to implement struct polymorphism

Tags: c, struct, polymorphism, virtual-functions

The problem I'm facing in C is that I'd like to have a series of structs that have a base member from another struct. e.g.

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    void (*calculate)(struct foo *);
};
struct bar {
    int a;
    void (*calculate)(struct foo *);
    double b;
};
void do_thing(struct foo *a)
{
    a->calculate(a);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the following appears to violate strict aliasing rules.

```
void foo_calculate(struct foo *a)
{
    struct bar *b = (struct bar*)a;
}
```

The only way I've come up with to do this is to create a union inside `struct foo` that contains all the structs that inherit from it. Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does the previously mentioned thread help you?

Comment: @KennyMeyer I have no idea how I haven't seen that question before. That was almost the exact phrase I googled. It doesn't seem to account for strict aliasing rules though.

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980925/easy-struct-inheritance-pseudo-polymorphism-vs-strict-aliasing

Comment: also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477307/oo-polymorphism-in-c-aliasing-issues

Comment: I just answered a similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777451/is-it-possible-to-do-inheritance-from-an-abstract-base-struct-or-simulate-someth/34781775#34781775

Comment: @CraigEstey can you mark this question as a duplicate of that thread?

Comment: @CraigEstey you got it

Comment: @KennyMeyer done ...

Comment: I don't understand how I'm supposed to be able to access the derived class members, from a virtual function, in a solutions like this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777451/is-it-possible-to-do-inheritance-from-an-abstract-base-struct-or-simulate-someth

Comment: In addition to the SO question you are looking at, for an excellent article/tutorial on incomplete datatypes, encapsulation, data-hiding, dynamic linkage/late binding and object oriented approaches to dynamic data-structures, see [**Object Oriented Programming in ANSI-C**](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf). While it is written at, and requires, a fairly in-depth knowledge of C, it is well worth the effort requierd to digest the material. It covers a number of topics not included in most C books or tutorials.

Comment: It may or may not violate strict aliasing rules, but your approach is similar to mine [in the link]. If the compiler is complaining, try casting to `void *` on the right hand side. There are other answers, but mine is what I've used [with success] for years.

Comment: Don't use compilers which don't guarantee (and document) good behaviour. Funky optimisations based on close reading of the standard such as "strict aliasing rules" or "assume possible undefined behaviour is never triggered" is bad behaviour. For, e.g. GCC, that means you have to explicitly disable quite a lot of optimisations.