# Is casting structures defined behaviour

Tags: c, struct, undefined-behavior

You can cast (pointers to) structs in C quite easily:

For example there is struct A:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}A;
```

and a struct B:

```
typedef struct {
    A parent;
    int c;
}B;
```

Now if `x` is a pointer to a struct B, I could do the following:

`A *a_struct = (A*) x;`

Now I am asking if this is actual defined behaviour or if it is just 'random' that it works with (some) compilers (I tested it with `gcc`)

Comment: Yes, it's defined behavior in *this specific case*. I'm in a cafeteria right now, so if you need searching this site to find the no-doubt several duplicates of this question, it may be awhile unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: This question seems to be about the same thing: [Does accessing the first field of a struct via a C cast violate strict aliasing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747010/does-accessing-the-first-field-of-a-struct-via-a-c-cast-violate-strict-aliasing)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? To know that the cast is well defined you have to know that the source type is `B`. So why not just use `&X->parent` ?

Comment: @JensGustedt think of something like an object system, where child 'classes' have their 'parent' as first property. This makes sure that a child class can still be used with functions expecting the parent class. And after a curtain number of children it is getting pretty confusing using `->parent`. Think of something like the 8th child, you would need: `X->parent->parent->parent->parent->parent->parent->parent->parent` (it looks a bit confusing)